# Getting dataKey value for each row in grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, datakey

I am having some problem when trying to get the data keys value from grid view. Here is the code:

```
GridView gvForCheckBox = (GridView)e.Item.FindControl("gvProduct") as GridView;
foreach (GridViewRow gr in gvForCheckBox.Rows)
{
    //If product name of items in prodList and SPUItemList matches
    if (available.Where(x => x.id == gr.Cells[0].Text).Any())
    {
        //Mark the checkBox checked
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)gr.Cells[0].FindControl("cbCheckRow");
        cb.Checked = true;

        //Get the product packaging quantity by productName
        string name = gr.Cells[1].Text;
        int productQuantity = packBLL.getProductQuantityByName(name);
        TextBox tb = (TextBox)gr.Cells[3].FindControl("tbQuantity");
        tb.Text = productQuantity.ToString();
    }
}
```

At `if (available.Where(x => x.id == gr.Cells[0].Text).Any())`, it's supposed to compare with the value of column 0 row by row, if id matched, then the check box will be marked. However, I did not display an id column in my grid view but I set it as DataKey value. So I wonder how to get the datakey for each row in a grid view.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming `x.id` is a string, you can get the DataKey value using `gvForCheckBox.DataKeys[gr.RowIndex].Value.ToString()` inside the `foreach` loop:

```
foreach (GridViewRow gr in gvForCheckBox.Rows)
{
    //If product name of items in prodList and SPUItemList matches
    if (available.Where(x => x.id == gvForCheckBox.DataKeys[gr.RowIndex].Value.ToString()).Any())
    {
        //Mark the checkBox checked
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)gr.Cells[0].FindControl("cbCheckRow");
        cb.Checked = true;

        //Get the product packaging quantity by productName
        string name = gr.Cells[1].Text;
        int productQuantity = packBLL.getProductQuantityByName(name);
        TextBox tb = (TextBox)gr.Cells[3].FindControl("tbQuantity");
        tb.Text = productQuantity.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: It told me possible unintended comparison; to get a value comparison, cast the right to string green error message

Comment: I am still having problem to mark the check box checked by comparing the id. Would you mind to help me solve it in another thread?

Answer (score 2):

You should try this

```
GridView gvForCheckBox = (GridView)e.Item.FindControl("gvProduct") as GridView;
                    foreach (GridViewRow gr in gvForCheckBox.Rows)
                    {

int rowIndex = gr.RowIndex;
string val = (string)gvForCheckBox .DataKeys[rowIndex]["myKey"];
                        //If product name of items in prodList and SPUItemList matches
                        if (available.Where(x => x.id == val ).Any())
                        {
                            //Mark the checkBox checked
                            CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)gr.Cells[0].FindControl("cbCheckRow");
                            cb.Checked = true;

                            //Get the product packaging quantity by productName
                            string name = gr.Cells[1].Text;
                            int productQuantity = packBLL.getProductQuantityByName(name);
                            TextBox tb = (TextBox)gr.Cells[3].FindControl("tbQuantity");
                            tb.Text = productQuantity.ToString();
                        }
                    }
```

here i have determime rowindex of current row and than find datakey value for this row with help of his code

```
int rowIndex = gr.RowIndex;
string val = (string)gvForCheckBox.DataKeys[rowIndex]["myKey"];
```

Comment: There is an error at this line: string val = (string)this.gvForCheckBox.DataKeys[rowIndex]["id"]; near gvForCheckBox. It said missing reference

Comment: @Gwen now please try i have removed this before gridview name.

Answer (score 1):

EXAMPLE

HEAD GRIDVIEW

```
DataKeyNames="PrecioSinIva, PorcentajeIva"
```

COLUMNS GRIDVIEW

```
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="PRECIOSINIVA" DataField="PrecioSinIva" Visible="false"/>    
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="PORCENTAJEIVA" DataField="PorcentajeIva" Visible="false"/>  

foreach (GridViewRow rowDatos in this.uiTrabajosAgregadosVales.Rows)
{
  if (rowDatos.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
  string precioSinIva =iTrabajosAgregadosVales.DataKeys[rowDatos.RowIndex].Values[0].ToString();
  string porcentajeIva =iTrabajosAgregadosVales.DataKeys[rowDatos.RowIndex].Values[1].ToString();    
  }
}
```